# how do I give a provisioning app to another person?

Tags: iphone, provisioning

I have a developed an iphone application. The web service was developed by someone who is remote and does not have a developer account / xcode etc. He does have iTunes though.

Is there a way for me to allow his iphone to install the application without him having to create a developer account, have xcode etc? A way to make the application available to his iTunes would be ideal.

Is this possible?

Many thanks,
Fidel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get his iPhone device UDID. Then create a distribution profile for ad-hoc distribution and add his UDID to the profile. Create a distribution build of your app and sign with that distribution profile. Send over the build .app and the .mobileprovision (provisioning profile) to him. He will have to install the profile first via iTunes (drag and drop to Library section and then sync) and then similarly he can install the app once the profile is successfully installed.